# virtuemart google checkout plugin

Tags: joomla, google-checkout, virtuemart

does anyone knows how to implement the google checkout plugin for virtue-mart. Because the plug-ins out there for virtue-mart google checkout are commercial. And I would like to have an answer on how to get one from the internet or how to code the plug-in for google

looking forward for your valuable response

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there are no free Joomla/VM Google checkout payment modules. There are 2 levels of integration of Google checkout -

Level 1 - Order handling is done on the Google merchant site and implementation is only requires the ability to generate an HTML form with the shopping cart information.

Level 2 - Order information is passed back to VM and order handling and updating is done in VM. This require considerably more programming knowledge and the ability to generate and read XML files.

You can find documentation here - [Google Code](https://checkout.google.com/sell2/settings?section=ThirdPartyCarts&thirdPartyCarts=checkoutApi)
You can find sample code here - [Sample Code](http://code.google.com/p/google-checkout-php-sample-code/)